# Cloud Foundry API access credentials for Custom Service

Tags: service, authorization, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm developing a custom cloud foundry service for IBM Bluemix. When the service is provisioned by a user, I need my service to call the Cloud Foundry API and retrieve some information about the org for which the service is being provisioned. I see that I can do that by calling an API endpoint such as [this one](http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/250/organizations/get_organization_summary.html).

Where do I get the Authorization token that my service will use to access the CF API? I don't want to use the token for my user account, which is all I seem to have access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Foundry does not support this scenario today, but there are proposals on the table like this one to support this in the future.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DoAbJa_YiGIJbOZ_zPzakh7sc4TB9Tmadq41cfSX0dw/edit#heading=h.j004km5ma4pj